# Where pip is located when installed with --user?

Tags: python, pip

I have an account on a linux machine without root access. Python and pip are installed but I don't want to install their version, I want to install my own python.

So I went to http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html and downloaded get-pip.py. Then I ran it with the existing python like this:

```
/usr/bin/python get-pip.py --user
```

Then the output was this:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py:3: UserWarning: Module pip was already imported from /tmp/tmpuuEbJv/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py, but /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=4d4fb4b69df6731c7aea6300bc1f2
  Downloading pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.0MB): 1.0MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
```

But now where is the new pip is installed? Which directory?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Alternate installation: the user scheme](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme):

> Files will be installed into subdirectories of **site.USER_BASE** (written
>   as userbase hereafter). This scheme installs pure Python modules and
>   extension modules in the same location (also known as site.USER_SITE).
>   Here are the values for UNIX, including Mac OS X:
>
> ```
> Type of file | Installation directory
> -------------+---------------------------------------
> modules      | userbase/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages
> scripts      | userbase/bin
> data         | userbase
> C headers    | userbase/include/pythonX.Y/distname
>
> And here are the values used on Windows:
>
> Type of file | Installation directory
> -------------+---------------------------------------
> modules      | userbase\PythonXY\site-packages
> scripts      | userbase\Scripts
> data         | userbase
> C headers    | userbase\PythonXY\Include\distname
> ```

---

```
>>> import site
>>> site.USER_BASE  # `falsetru` is my username.
'/home/falsetru/.local'
>>> os.path.join(site.USER_BASE, 'bin')
'/home/falsetru/.local/bin'
```